# Can someone explain pls why the Promise returns pending in the first function, but resolved in the other two?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Can someone explain pls why the Promise returns pending in the first function, but resolved in the other two? When i read MDN it states that just using the word async wont make the code inside asynchronous (we need to use the word await as well). Also, I return the promise explicitly, since I use resolve() (which should return fulfilled promise as in two other functions, yet it returns Pending in the first function). I provided the code below.

```js
const testFunc = async() => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    resolve()
  })
}

const testFunc2 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    resolve()
  })
}

const testFunc3 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    resolve()
  })
}

testFunc().then(()=> console.log("Hello")).then(()=> console.log("there")).then(()=> console.log("Obi One"))

testFunc2().then(()=> console.log(1)).then(()=> console.log(2)).then(()=> console.log(3))

testFunc3().then(()=> console.log(4)).then(()=> console.log(5)).then(()=> console.log(6))

console.log(testFunc())
console.log(testFunc2())
console.log(testFunc3())

// Results in the console: 
// Promise {<pending>}
// Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
// Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
// 1
// 4
// 2
// 5
// Hello
// 3
// 6
// there
```

Comment: Resolving a promise with another promise (even if already fulfilled) takes a bit of them. Don't fret, this normally never happens in real asynchronous functions that actually wait for something.

Comment: It could be the strings in the debug print are delaying in more than the others.  Try swapping the arguments to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `testFunc` (the function with async keyword) is equalevent to this:

```js
const testFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    resolve(new Promise((r) => {
      r()
    }))
  })
}
```

and not

```js
const testFunc = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
    resolve()
  })
}
```

Comment: so we resolve the promise twice here? is that because Async always returns promise? I thought if the code inside an async function returns promise it wont wrap it inside another promise?

Comment: Yes, we are creating nested promises there. if you do this it returns one promise: `async () => await new Promise(...)`

Answer (score -1):

Using async queues the executer as a microtask.

Read about it here: https://whistlr.info/2021/async-and-tasks/

The key point:

> When you write an asynchronous function, you force the caller to use a microtask to read its result. This is the case even if you don't await inside it—it will return a Promise regardless

Comment: const testFunc = async() => {
return 1

}

console.log(testFunc()).  // Fulfilled                                                                                        If we use await in front of 1, it will be pending

Comment: Yes, that is my point. Adding the async keyword does affect the code, contrary to the MDN explaination.

Comment: Also adding async DOES make the code async, even if you don't return a promise. It will return a resolved promise implicitly. try to return Promise.resolve() from your functions to see if that changes behavior.